# How do I shutdown Oracle automatically every Friday at 10pm?

Tags: server, cron

You install oracle database but need to shutdown at night every Friday at 10pm so that you can make backups. How would you achieve this automatically using the crontab utility? Assume that the script that shutdown and backups the database in called backup.sh and located in /opt/scripts

Answer (score 2):

Back up `/etc/crontab` and then edit it to add this line:

`0 22 * * 5 root /opt/scripts/backup.sh`

(This assumes the script has execute permissions. If not, then put `sh`  in front of the command.)

If the script is to be run by some user other than `root`, replace `root` with the appropriate username.

By the way, I highly recommend `man 5 crontab`, which documents the full format for crontabs. (Also [available online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=crontab&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/).)

Comment: Great...this is awesome..Now which utility can i use to backup my Linux PC once only. assuming that the script to run in is /opt/script/once.sh?

Comment: Depending on when you want it to happen, you might just run the script (`/opt/script/once.sh` or `sh /opt/script/once.sh`, or with `sudo` if it needs to run as `root`: `sudo /opt/script/once.sh` or `sudo sh /opt/script/once.sh`), or you might schedule it with the [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/at.1.html) command if you want it to run at a single particular date/time later (`echo /opt/script/once.sh | at now + 10 3 days` or, to give an example with `sudo` and where `once.sh` is non-executable: `echo sh /opt/script/once.sh | sudo at 11pm`).

Comment: But that sounds like a separate question; if you want more information about running scripts or scheduling actions to occur at a single specific date/time, I recommend posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Open your crontab with `crontab -e`. If it's your first time, you'll be presented with a list of editors to choose from.

Now add this line to your crontab file

```
0 22 * * 5 sh /opt/scripts/backup.sh
```

save and close.

Comment: This is for a system administration task, so the user crontab is probably not the most appropriate way to achieve this. (The script likely has to run either as root or as a user that cannot actually log in, but exists only for running the database. In the former case, this must be the systemwide crontab or--much less preferably--the root user's per-user crontab. In the latter case, the special database user likely doesn't have the ability to schedule tasks via cron.)